Find the longest item in array of strings in MongoDB
A have a collection Products in MongoDB:
{
  "name": "My Product 01",
  "description": "This is an excelent product", 
  "tags": [
    "AA",
    "BBBB",
    "C",
    "DDDDDDDDDDD"
  ]  
}

How can I find the single longest occurrence of an item in the whole collection? (if I had only this object, the longest occurrence would be "DDDDDDDDDDD" with 11 characters).

do you mean individual objects longest tag, or whole collection?

What have you tried? Have you checked out $strLenCP?

I mean the longest occurence of a tag in the whole collection.

$unwind to tags level. Use $strLenCP to compute the length. Use $setWindowFields to $rank the length. $match rank: 1 to select the one(s) with longest length.
db.Products.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$tags"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "length": {
        "$strLenCP": "$tags"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "length": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      rank: 1
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

db.Products.aggregate([
  // Unwind the tags array
  {
    $unwind: "$tags"
  },
  // Project each tag with its length
  {
    $project: {
      tag: "$tags",
      length: {
        $strLenCP: "$tags"
      }
    }
  },
  // Sort by length in descending order
  {
    $sort: {
      length: -1
    }
  },
  // Limit to the longest tag
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  // Project only the tag field
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      tag: 1
    }
  }
])

generates:
[
  {
    "tag": "DDDDDDDDDDD"
  }
]

